# How to store curl data and use function on it from another variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

I have a curl and I want to use it multiple times with different variable. but for now I am having hard time storing it cause it can't even `json_pretty.sh` it. Here is the image of the execution.

The echo command(on yellow circle image below) only working, but when I try to store it into variable (on red circle image below ) it doesn't work anymore.

[image]

and here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
json_file=$(cat response.json) # I will change this to CURL, .json is temporary

echo $json_file | sh json_pretty.sh

SenderAccountNumber=$(echo $json_file | sh json_pretty.sh )

echo $SenderAccountNumber
```

Comment: You might want to look into `jq` if you're trying to extract one specific datum from a chunk of JSON.  (Some of) Your output problems may stem from sending unquoted data to `echo`, which helpfully lets the shell eat all of the whitespace for you if you don't do so.

Comment: @DopeGhoti sorry, I am using `jq` earlier, but my sir doesn't want a 3rd party install. so I try to use native as possible. this is the last piece of my code to complete it already but stuck on the assigning value.

Comment: Please provide textual data in your question as text not as screenshots.

Comment: `jq` is a tool of choice to use JSON files. Don't try (and fail badly) to redo it in some other ways, like in shell script.

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086). I'm willing to help, but I really can't read your screen dumps, or understand what your drawing on them is supposed to show.

Answer (score 0):

Is Python acceptable? If yes, you can use `echo $json_file | python -m json.tool` for pretty-printing. Regarding the problem, use quotes: `echo "$SenderAccountNumber"`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character.